# Set width of Bootstrap 4 navbar overlay to nav contents

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I would like to set the width of the Bootstrap 4 navbar overlay, when it is shown by clicking on the hamburger icon, to match its contents, rather than take up the whole screen. I've looked through the navbar, navbar-collapse, and navbar-nav classes, some flex documentation, and I'm not yet clear how to do this.

Comment: Can you post the code please?

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize the fact that the `navbar-toggler` can also handle things outside the navbar.

So, you'd create a `container` outside the navbar, put a `row` inside and a `col-auto` into that row.

Putting the entire `collapse navbar-collapse` div into that auto-column will now do exactly what you desire. The only disadvantage is that for the expanded state of the navbar, you'd have to have a duplicate of the navbar-item list inside the navbar.

Also note that you need to add `style="margin-top: -1px !important"` to external container because otherwise it will stick out by one pixel. (`m-0` removes the regular margin on the container)

Here's a working code snippet (click "run code snippet" below):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-DISABLED navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img class="brand-icon mr-2" src="https://placehold.it/60" width="30" height="30" alt="">Company
    </a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
</nav>
   
<div class="container m-0" style="margin-top: -1px !important">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-auto navbar-dark bg-dark">
           <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
               <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                   <li class="nav-item active">
                       <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                   </li>
                   <li class="nav-item">
                       <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                   </li>
                   <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                       <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                           Dropdown
                       </a>
                       <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                           <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                           <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                           <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                           <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                       </div>
                   </li>
                   <li class="nav-item">
                       <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                   </li>
               </ul> 
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```